# Cannot Link To C++ GLFW Dependency In Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dependencies, glfw

I'm attempting to include and use the [GLFW Library](https://www.glfw.org/) in my [Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) Project.

I have followed the steps outlined in [this tutorial](http://www.mcihanozer.com/tips/setting-up-libraries/setting-up-glfw-for-visual-studio/), I have also followed other tutorials which have the exact same steps, but alas, I cannot get it to work.

Please see the screenshots below for my Project settings, directory hierarchy and basic hello world file.

[image: 1]]

[image: 2]]

[image: 3]]

[image: 4]]

[image: 5]]

Comment: Oh I see. You made the settings for x64 but you are compiling your code for 32 bit. Looks like you choose the wrong configuration to build in the first image.

Comment: @drescherjm wow thanks my guy, that fixed it completely! If you post that as a question-answer I'll mark it as correct :)

Comment: I am not sure if this should just be closed as a typo. Although with that said you did a reasonable job of presenting the question.